# How to understand CQL3 table model from scratch?

Tags: cassandra, implementation, cql3, column-family

I recently visited http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#CQLSyntax and just read this:

> [...] please note that as such, they do not refer to the concept of
>   rows and columns found in the internal implementation of Cassandra and
>   in the thrift and CQL v2 API.

If we assume that I've understood Cassandras data model (column family, etc.) I do not understand where CQL3 differs from?
Is the table model of CQL3 related to Cassandras Column Family however?
I mean, how about perfomance issues?
How is the CQL3 implementation compared to the relational tables?

**What is the internal implementation and/or concept of CQL3's row-and-column-model?**
I know that there is something like Composite Column model. Is this the difference to the classical Cassandra row-column-model?
Moreover I am interested in theoretical details.

Asking these questions: What did I not understand?

Unfortunately I just started getting deeper into CQL. But I am very familiar with the cassandra-cli and (my)SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your one-stop-shopee to learn CQL data model:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much. And if I have understood the article rightly it refers to the "Composite Columns" which makes the difference to the classical Column Family model. Trought the "Composite Columns" we have a denormalization of the data but we get more performance. **Am I right or wrong?**

Comment: With de-normalization, the read queries which specifies the rowkeys in the query, essentially Cassandra has to do a point lookup from a node where data exists and it is fastest.